# Using javascript to "link" from html background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having looked elsewhere on the website it seemed to me to be a bit tricky to get a background image in html to be a link also.  In looking around I stumbled across somebody's suggestion that using java script should do the trick.  However in testing the idea out i have had no luck.

I would be very grateful if somebody could point out where i am going wrong.

I have the following html and javascript  code:

```
<html>

<head>
<link href = "style1.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
</head>

<div id = "header">
Header
</div>

<body>

<div id = "body">

<div class = "container">

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>

<script>
document.getElementById('container').onclick = function() {
window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
}
</script>
```

I also have the following CSS:

```
#header{
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:black;
}

#body {
width:100%;
height:2000px;
background-image:url('uploads/1.jpg');
cursor:pointer;
}


.container{
 width: 1000px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 1000px;
background-color:white;

}
```

Comment: There is literally like 10 ways to do this. Your code should work if you just either add an id to your div with the container class. However, I would probably do this without javascript as there is no need. If you need your anchor to behave like an div, just set it to display: block;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `.getElementById('container')`

When `container` is actually a class.

can also do `<div class="container" onClick="goToWebsite()"></div>`

```
<script>
 function goToWebsite() {
 window.location = 'http://google.com';
}
</script>
```

Comment: sorry that because i tried that also.  It still doesn't work when it is "body".

Comment: oh it did...ever so sorry.  Out of interest.  Why doesn't it work when i have "getelementByClass" or whatever?

Comment: You would need to use `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: I have a problem.  When I have getElementById('body') and not container for some reason I am linked to google - as an example - even when i click on the container.  How would i go about making the link work exclusively for the body?

Comment: The body tag encompasses the whole document. So your whole site inside <body id="body"> would be clickable. I suggest not to have that functionality on the body tag.

Comment: Whoops, thought you had the id of body ON <body>. Anything inside <div id="body"> would be clickable.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to make the container one large link?  The trick here is setting `display:block`.  Also as of HTML5 this is perfectly valid.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
   <link href = "style1.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
</head>

<div id = "header">
Header
</div>

<body>

    <div id = "body">

        <a class="container" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
   display: block; 
   width: 1000px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   height: 1000px;
   background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: This would be the best approach.

Comment: My issue is resolved now.  But i am certainly interested in doing as you suggested as well.  I'll give it a go as well.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with pure HTML as well for this example.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><div id="image-link"></div></a>
```

This way you have a link for that div and then in the style sheet you can add a background image to be click able.  The CSS portion would look like this:

```
#image-link {
        background-image:url('untitled.jpg');
}
```

Just change the location of the background image to what ever of course.