# How to exclude the container from this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question relates to the last i asked on this site - [Using javascript to "link" from html background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697735/using-javascript-to-link-from-html-background-image).

I received a good answer which worked, however the link for the background image is also applied to the container.  How would I go about ensuring that only clicking on the background image (of the id body) and not the container links to whatever website?

I hope I have been clear enough.  Many thanks in advance.

The html:

```
<html>

<head>
<link href = "style1.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
</head>

<div id = "header">
Header
</div>

<body>

<div id = "body">

<div class = "container">

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>

<script>
document.getElementById('body').onclick = function() {
window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
}
</script>
```

The CSS code:

```
#header{
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:black;
}

#body {
width:100%;
height:2000px;
background-image:url('uploads/1.jpg');
cursor:pointer;
}


.container{
 width: 1000px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 1000px;
background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java. Also, please post the code you have now.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I will do..

Comment: This doesn't warrant the need for a new question.  You could of just asked this on the comments of the answer you accepted, as it's heavily related.

Comment: I see.  I'm relatively new with this site.

Comment: You can't have a `<div>` *outside* of your `<body>` like that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your click handler, you can check the element that was clicked on, if it's not `body` (meaning it's a child), then don't do anything.

```
document.getElementById('body').onclick = function(e) {
    // e.target is what you clicked on
    // this is always what the event was bound to
    if(e.target === this){
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
    }
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using?  It worked for me in IE 9 and Chrome 25.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this code in your script:

```
document.querySelector('#body .container').onclick = function() {return false; }
```

To have:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('body').onclick = function() {
window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
}
document.querySelector('#body .container').onclick = function() {return false; }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a return false

```
document.getElementById('body').onclick = function(e)
{
    if(!(e.target===this))
        return false;
    console.log("click");
    //window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
}
```